# dplyr summarise Error in str.default(obj, ...) dims [product 11] do not match the length of object [3]

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, dplyr, summary

I am having a very frustrating problem using `dplyr` `group_by` and `summarise` functions.

This is my dataset:

```
> cum_ems_totals
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]

   Chamber Total_emmissions Treatment  Block
    <fctr>            <dbl>    <fctr> <fctr>
1        1        5769.0507         U      1
2        3        7790.1426        IU      1
3        4        5166.8992        AN      1
4        5        7625.7319        AN      2
5        6        1964.0970        IU      2
6        7        5052.1268         U      2
7        9        4207.5324        IU      3
8       10         470.7014        AN      3
9       12        5675.9171         U      3
10      14        5666.1678         U      4
11      15        2134.5002        AN      4
12      16        4093.4687        IU      4

> str(cum_ems_totals)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   12 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Chamber         : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","3","4","5",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 ...
 $ Total_emmissions: num [1:101, 1] 5769 7790 5167 7626 1964 ...
 $ Treatment       : Factor w/ 4 levels "U","IU","AN",..: 1 2 3 3 2 1 2 3 1 1 ...
 $ Block           : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","13",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 ...
```

I now want to calculate some summary stats by Treatment so:

```
cum_ems_summary <- cum_ems_totals %>% filter(Chamber != "10") %>% 
  group_by(Treatment) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), Mean = mean(Total_emmissions, na.rm = TRUE),
                      SD = sd(Total_emmissions, na.rm = TRUE), SEM = SD/sqrt(n))
```

Which gives me:

```
> cum_ems_summary
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

  Treatment     n     Mean        SD       SEM
     <fctr> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1         U     4 5540.816  329.0763  164.5381
2        IU     4 4513.810 2415.6355 1207.8178
3        AN     3 4975.710 2750.6038 1588.0618
```

So far so good. However, if I try and graph this data using `ggplot` I get the following error:

```
> ggplot(cum_ems_summary, aes(x = Treatment, y = Mean, fill = Treatment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 11
```

The `str` of the dataframe gives this:

```
> str(cum_ems_summary)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Treatment: Factor w/ 4 levels "U","IU","AN",..: 1 2 3
 $ n        : int  4 4 3
 $ Mean     :
Error in str.default(obj, ...) : 
  dims [product 11] do not match the length of object [3]
```

I don't understand what is going on here! Can anyone help out?

Comment: @Sumedh done that but it still gives me the same error

Comment: `Total_emmissions` is not a regular vector. It is a one column matrix. Note the two values in the structure `[1:101, 1]` Coerce it to a vector.

Comment: @PierreLafortune i wondered what the `[1:101,1]` was all about. Any ideas how that may have occured? `cum_ems_totals <- cum_ems %>% group_by(Chamber) %>% 
  summarise(Total_emmissions = last(cumulative_emissions))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune coercing to a vector does the job. Thanks

Comment: No idea how it occurred. It's difficult to make that happen. I would have to see everything that came before it. The fix was added as an answer.

Comment: @PierreLafortuneI have added another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640268/matrix-appearing-inside-a-dataframe-how-has-this-happened with more details on the dataframe - would be great if you could have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#Reproduce error
str(cum_ems_summary)
# Error in str.default(obj, ...) : 
#   dims [product 11] do not match the length of object [3]

#Fix
cum_ems_totals$Total_emmissions <- c(cum_ems_totals$Total_emmissions)


#Try again
cum_ems_summary <- cum_ems_totals %>% filter(Chamber != "10") %>% 
  group_by(Treatment) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), Mean = mean(Total_emmissions, na.rm = TRUE),
            SD = sd(Total_emmissions, na.rm = TRUE), SEM = SD/sqrt(n))

ggplot(cum_ems_summary, aes(x = Treatment, y = Mean, fill = Treatment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue and solved it by adding a mutate_if at the end, in case it helps:

```
df2<- df%>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(scale, mean)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.matrix, as.vector)
```

Answer (score -1):

could the error message not be related to the fact that your Treatment has 4 levels? When it should have 3 levels "U","IU","AN" and levels assigned are 1, 2, 3 and the extra level ".." doesn't have a number assigned to it.